# SQL - Group two rows by columns that value and null on different columns

Tags: sql, presto

### Question

Say I have a table with such rows:

```
id | country | place | last_action | second_to_last_action
----------------------------------------------------------
1  |   US    |   2   |   reply     | 
1  |   US    |   2   |             |       comment
4  |   DE    |   5   |   reply     | 
4  |         |       |             |       comment
```

What I want to do is to combine these by id, country and place so that the last_action and second_to_last_action would be on the same row

```
id | country | place | last_action | second_to_last_action
----------------------------------------------------------
1  |   US    |   2   |   reply     |      comment
4  |   DE    |   5   |   reply     |      comment
```

How would I approach this? I guess I would need an aggregate here but my mind is hitting completely blank on which one should I use.

It can be expected that there will always be a matching pair.

### Background:

Note: this table has been derived from something like this:

```
id | country | place |   action    | time
----------------------------------------------------------
1  |   US    |   2   |   reply     |    16:15
1  |   US    |   2   |   comment   |    15:16
1  |   US    |   2   |   view      |    13:16
4  |   DE    |   5   |   reply     |    17:15
4  |   DE    |   5   |   comment   |    16:16
4  |   DE    |   5   |   view      |    14:12
```

Code used to partition was:

```
row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc) as event_no
```

And then I got the last and second_to_last action by getting event_no 1 & 2. So if there's more efficient way to get the last two actions in two distinct columns I would be happy to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your first data by using aggregation:

```
select id, country, place, max(last_action), max(second_to_last_action)
from derived
group by id, country, place;
```

You can do this from the original table using conditional aggregation:

```
select id, country, place,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then action end) as last_action,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then action end) as second_to_last_action
from (select t.*,
            row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, country, place;
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was an aggregate for that (tbh, I think've used Max at some point for this exact same situation) but I couldn't find it at all